# What's the shortest way to end multiple process at windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows, process, task-manager

Is it there any simple way to end multiple process in task manager of windows 7,

**Scenario** :

I need to end multiple process at task manager ,since there is no option for **Multi-select** ,Any option to end multiple process at same time via task manager.

Kindly have a look at the sample snap below,i need to end all the process which was listed at snapshot,Ending the process one by one is time consuming ,so looking for any option to end multiple process at  a time?

[image]

Kindly show the shortest way to end multiple process at a time in task manager

Installing third party tools wont be a option since its in corporate environment i wont get access to installation of third party tools,other than that any shortest way to achieve this ?

Comment: Instead of fighting symptoms of what appears to be a malware infection, you might want to [take a look at this](http://superuser.com/q/100360/219095).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found one way which can be done via 'Taskkill' command

**Steps** :

1. Go to Command line
2. Run the following command :

> ```
>  taskkill /f /im xx.exe
> ```

Replace xx with the name of the exe

the above steps will kill all the process with the particular name

Comment: It's not possible to end multiple processes in the taskmanager But like already written, you can use taskkill. Create a CMD-File on your Desktop or desired location, maybe in the Startup-Folder? More Informations: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb491009.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Inside Task Manager, select the Performance tab. At the bottom, click Open Resource Monitor. (Or press <kbd>**⊞** Win</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> and enter `resmon`.)

Now use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> click or <kbd>Shift</kbd> to select multiple processes. Right click one of them and choose End Process.